# How to create a valid AAF from scratch using `OpenTimelineIO`?

Tags: python, timeline, davinci-resolve

When I create an **AAF timeline** from scratch using the `OpenTimelineIO` library, I get an error: `"AAFAdapterError: Cannot find mob ID for clip".`

Surfing the internet, I only see solutions regarding **pulling those Mob IDs from an existing AAF**, but how to create a valid AAF from scratch using `OpenTimelineIO`, (like AVID or DaVinci Resolve does)?

I try to create them manually using the `pyaaf2` library with the `aaf2.mobs.MobID().new()` method and manually add it to the clip metadata. The timeline still won't work properly (for example, when importing the timeline into `DaVinci Resolve 18`, it can't find the previously added .mov files in it).